# WCF The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am calling WCF service from web application. It works fine for local webservice. When service deployed to dev server, it gives me above error. Webservice returns List of custom objects in xml format.

```
[OperationContract()]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/track/get", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    List<tokenCount> GetTracking(System.IO.Stream data);
```

If I return just a string from webservice, it works fine. Other operations in webservice work fine.

```
        oRequest.ContentLength = aBytes.Length;
        oRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        oRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        oRequest.ConnectionGroupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        oRequest.Timeout = 60000; 
        using (Stream oRequestStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            oRequestStream.Write(aBytes, 0, aBytes.Length);               
            using (HttpWebResponse oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";                     
                    //resDoc = CreateMetaFile(oReader.ReadToEnd());
                    string r = oReader.ReadToEnd(); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

How **many** objects are you returning??

If that number gets high, you could run into two problems:

- timeout: the server could take too long to get the answer ready and WCF will terminate the call
- size: your size could exceed the settings for `maxReceivedMessageSize` on your client and thus be aborted

Comment: Currently I kept only one record which statisfies the condition and returns from the webservice.

Comment: webapplication locally, webservice remote gives above error. Webappllication locally and webservice locally can return 10 objects. where do I need to set maxRecivedMessageSize property?

Comment: @devel - `maxReceivedMessageSize` is set in your service configuration in your clients `<bindings>` within the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the clients config file